# Как правильно залить .NET проект на GitHub (удаление и восстановление пакетов)?

Tags: asp.net-core, github

Есть небольшой проект `MVC Core`, хочу залить его на `GitHub`. Но сначала надо удалить установленные пакеты, с возможностью последующего восстановления на локальной машине.

Другими словами.
Если это был бы проект с `React`, то там всё просто:

1. Вручную удаляются пакеты из папки `npm_modules`, проект отправляется на ГитХаб.
2. Потом юзер стянул проект на локальную машину и восстановил их командой `npm install`.

В случае с `MVC Core` понимаю, что:

1. В `.csproj` есть тег `ItemGroup`, а в нём `<PackageReference...` где прописан каждый пакет. Такой аналог `requirments.txt` в питоне.
2. Удаление и восстановление пакетов вроде бы запускается командами `dotnet clean` и `dotnet restore`, но разобраться что-то не могу.

Собственно, вопросы:

- Как правильно удалить пакеты?
- Какие именно? Претенденты на удаление в `/bin/debug/net6.0` папка `runtimes` и много `.dll`)
- Как восстановить их локально после клонирования проекта?

Comment: `Вручную удаляются пакеты из папки npm_modules, проект отправляется на ГитХаб.` -- `node_modules` обычно добавляются в файл `.gitignore` без надобности удаления, они просто не заливаются на гит. Или Вы думаете что при работе в команде, кто-то перед каждой заливкой на гит, сносит пакеты, а потом их ставит?

Comment: "Или Вы думаете что при работе в команде, кто-то перед каждой заливкой на гит, сносит пакеты, а потом их ставит" - я действительно так думал, спасибо что поправили.

Comment: [Omitting NuGet packages in source control systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control)

Comment: По .gitignore нашёл вот такое https://gist.github.com/indyfromoz/4109296, 
и видимо этот вопрос можно закрыть. Но как потом восстановить все пакеты?

Answer (score 1):

Вам не надо удалять файлы, вам надо включить их в `.gitignore` чтобы они не заливались в гит.

Сами пакеты по умолчанию ставятся не в папку проекта, а в профиль пользователя - так что с ними проблемы вообще нет. Однако, ссылки на них появляются в папке `obj`, что ни на что не влияет потому что лишние тут не ссылки, а вся папка. По ссылке в комментариях не ходите, там написана устаревшая информация.

Правильный gitignore для проектов на C# такой:

```
.vs
obj/
bin/
```

То есть вы не выгружаете на сервер промежуточные файлы сборки (obj), итоговые бинарники (bin) и файлы среды разработки (.vs - это для Visual Studio, не стесняйтесь дописать сюда настройки для других IDE при необходимости).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но про гитигнор я нашёл и даже приложил ссылку с полным перечислением, вот она ещё раз  gist.github.com/indyfromoz/4109296. Но никто не ответил на третью часть вопроса 'Как восстановить их локально после клонирования проекта?'. Нашёл сам - команда 'dotnet restor'e восстанавливает папку obj, потом запускаем VS и при запуске она (VS) подхватывает и (видимо) восстанавливает остальное, проект запускается.

Comment: Можно и не запускать dotnet restore.  И даже студию открывать не обязательно.

Comment: Всё зависит от того что вам надо сделать с этими файлами. Если речь идёт о запуске - `dotnet run` в помощь. Если вам нужны бинарники - `dotnet build` или `dotnet publish` (там ещё куча настроек есть). Если цель в том чтобы открыть студию - то вы просто берёте и открываете студию. Ни один из этих сценариев не требует специальных действий по подготовке, с чего вы взяли что они вообще требуются?